# Can I refresh a div with knockoutJS rather than jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I would like to refresh a div with knockoutJS rather than jQuery when an image is clicked in the div.

for example I would like to click this image and not have it refresh the whole page, but just part of the page.

```
<img src="/images/xOut.png" id="cancelAction" data-bind="click: function(){isFreshIdea(!isFreshIdea());" style="cursor:pointer;position: absolute;" />
```

a bit like this is jQuery

```
$(function() {
  $(“#cancelAction”).click(function() {
     $(“#freshDiv”).load(Page.html + '#freshDiv')
  })
})
```

Is this possible?

Comment: So what you are looking to do is set the window.location.hash?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`html` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html) will bind HTML in a variable much like the `text` binding binds plain text. The refresh operation is just a matter of fetching the new content and putting it into the variable.

```js
vm = {
  refreshHtml: function() {
    /* You might do something like:
       $.get("http://www.mypage.com", vm.sectionContent, 'html');
       I'm simulating a fetch with this:
    */
    setTimeout(function() {
      vm.sectionContent('<h3>Something else</h3><div>Content has been swapped</div>');
    }, 500);
  },
  sectionContent: ko.observable('<h2>Change this</h2>')
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
.changeable {
  background-color: #eef;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=click+me&w=150&h=150&txttrack=0" data-bind="click: refreshHtml" />
<div>Some stuff</div>
<div class="changeable" data-bind="html:sectionContent"></div>
<div>Some more stuff</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest Knockout comes to loading remote content is [components with the require option](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html#example-loading-the-likedislike-widget-from-external-files-on-demand). Of course, you can always create a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).